# Using Linq to query a List<List<string>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of list of strings (e.g.  `List<List<string>>` )  - think of it as rows and columns in a spreadsheet.

The lists are dynamically created so the number of rows and columns can change.

I want to query the columns (the list within the list) (e.g.   `List<List<string>>` ) to see if a string matches, when it does then I want to return a new list that contains all the matching rows and columns within the rows. 
Basically I am letting a user enter a filter on a list and it will then display all the rows and columns that match (it needs match against any column preferably but I will be happy with an example that matches say the first col at this point).
I have tried several examples but they all just seem to return the columns as a list but no outer list above that (the rows).

Any help would be appreciated :)

Here is an example of the scenario using data

```
ColumnA   ColumnB     ColumnC
Mark       Australia   25
Marion     America     30
Fred       Dave        35
```

I want to be able to create a new `List<List<string>>` that contains the results of a filter being applied (preferably searching across all columns and rows but would be happy with an example that just checked the first column). So if my filter was `"Ma"` then I should get a `List<List<string>>`  back that contains 2 rows (in this case because it matches Mark and Marion) ... I don't want a list back that only has Mark and Marion, I need the 2 rows and all the columns for the 2 rows.

Comment: Question is a bit vague... can you expand and also report the "several" examples you tried?

Comment: Can you please show some example data? I can't see with which string the input string should match and what are the correspoding values you want to return.

Comment: Here is an example using data to show what I want.    `code`

Comment: I updated the description with some example data - sorry it wasn't clear (kind of hard to explain clearly :(  )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If all you need is to find a value in all lists and return the whole list if it was found:

```
string search = txtUserSearch.Text.Trim();
List<List<string>> searchResult = allLists
    .Where(list => list.Any(s => search.Equals(s, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)))
    .ToList();
```

If you don't need the case-insensitive search you can use:

```
.Where(list => list.Contains(search))
```

---

If you even want to find partial matches (substrings), you can use this:

```
.Where(list => list.Any(s => s != null && s.Contains(search)))
```

or case-insensitive:

```
.Where(list => list.Any(s => s != null && s.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
```

Comment: Thanks Tim Schmelter - works perfectly...... is there a trick to working these out so quickly? (some little test app or something?)

Comment: [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/). But if you have used LINQ often  it's getting more and more intuitive.